# Falha execução de Shell C#

Tags: c#, script, shell

Amigos, peço ajuda para resolver um pequeno problema.

Estou executando comando SQL através do sqlCmd e Shell no C#, porem o arquivo está em uma pasta que contém "espaço", conforme segue.

Path: D:\Sandboxes\**Projeto CIA**\3-Desenvolvimento\Scripts\DDL\DDL_T_DDW_CIA_PRODUTO_INDEXADOR.sql

Quando executo o Shell é exibido o erro:
Win32Exception: O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado

Existe alguma maneira de fazer o Shell entender o "espaço" no Path?

Segue comando que está sendo executado.

strScript = "sqlcmd -S *server* -i D:\Sandboxes\Projeto CIA\3-Desenvolvimento\Scripts\DDL\DDL_T_DDW_CIA_PRODUTO_INDEXADOR.sql"

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(strScript)

Obrigado

**Atualização**

Inclui as aspas duplas, porem o erro permanece.

```
sqlcmd -S servidor -U sa -P senha -i "D:\Pessoal\luiz.junior\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\AppNolock\AppNolock\bin\x86\Debug\Temp\Script.sql"
```

*Erro*:**O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado**

Answer (score 2):

Adicione aspas e escape-as da seguinte forma:

```
strScript = "sqlcmd -S server -i \"D:\\Sandboxes\\Projeto CIA\\3-Desenvolvimento\\Scripts\\DDL\\DDL_T_DDW_CIA_PRODUTO_INDEXADOR.sql\""
```

Note que tem de escapar os *backslashes*.

[Veja aqui o resultado](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GQCZ7J).

Comment: Omni, desculpe a demora, acabei me atrapalhando com outro projeto.
Fiz exatamente o que foi mencionado por você, porem o problema continua!!!

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema.

Ao invés de simplesmente Executar a linha de comando pelo Process.Start, criei um arquivo .bat com a linha de comando e esse foi executado pelo Process.Start.

```
            StringBuilder strScript = new StringBuilder();                
            var process = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();

            strScript.Append(String.Format("sqlcmd -S {0} -U sa -P mudar.123 -i \"{1}\"", cbServidor.Text, pathFile));
            Dados.GravarArquivo(PathTemp + @"\cmd.bat",strScript);
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(PathTemp + @"\cmd.bat");

            process.WorkingDirectory = file.Directory.FullName;
            process.FileName = file.Name;
            process.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(process).WaitForExit();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
```